# Converting tags to strings in PHP

Tags: php, tags, strip-tags

There is a function called strip_tags() that strips all tags from an input, and I'm wondering if there's a function that instead of stripping all tags from an input, converts them to string instead, like how stackoverflow does it when we indent our codes. And if there isn't, what should I use instead?

**output:**

*italic*

**need output:**

```
<i> italic </i>
```

Comment: It's not converting to string, it's escaping so that they are not processed. Use `htmlspecialchars()` or similar function to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Code:

```
$string = '<i> italic </i>';
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/483903

Output:

```
&lt;i&gt; italic &lt;/i&gt;
```

Which in a browser will render as:

> <i> italic </i>

Comment: So this does the same thing as strip_tags() in the sense that it does not allow users to execute scripts on our websites, right?

Comment: This will convert the elements to their entity equivalent. Strip_tags actually removes the element itself. A user could still XSS inject with this approach though depending on how you are outputting. Quotes could be used to close the attribute then `onclick`, etc. could be added..

Comment: What if we combine this with mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: That has no affect on XSS injections; that is for SQL injections.

Comment: What should we do instead, then, in this case?

Comment: Take a look at this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php and this doc; https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: The top answer said that we should use the htmlspecialchars() function, but he added 2 other parameters, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'. What does that do? Should I include those 2 parameters?

Comment: Yes, the `ENT_QUOTES` encodes `"`, and `'`. The third parameter is for the encoding type; different encodings have different characters for quotes. I didn't know this question was about XSS injections, thought it was just outputting controlled HTML to a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlspecialchars() as said in the comments or do it manually.

```
$str = "<i>something</i>";

echo str_replace("<", "&lt;", $str);
```